# What does a properties file looks like (Ant related)?

Tags: xml, ant

I am currently going through exercises and I am stuck on the  task. In this task, I have to create a properties file, but I am not sure what a properties file looks like. Is it a .xml or.java file?

I have been given this sample code:

```
<property name="build.debug" value="on"/>
<javac srcdir="src" debug="${build.debug}"/>
```

And execute the following command: >ant -Dbuild.debug=off –f yourBuildFile.xml

But, nothing outputs when I put those two lines of code in my .xml file.

Help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a java .properties file.  See this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties

**------------- EDIT ------------**

An ant build.xml should look something like this:

```
<project name="MyProject" default="dist" basedir=".">
    <description>
        simple example build file
    </description>
  <!-- set global properties for this build -->
  <property name="src" location="src"/>
  <property name="build" location="build"/>
  <property name="dist"  location="dist"/>

  <target name="init">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp/>
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile" depends="init"
        description="compile the source " >
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="dist" depends="compile"
        description="generate the distribution" >
    <!-- Create the distribution directory -->
    <mkdir dir="${dist}/lib"/>

    <!-- Put everything in ${build} into the MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar file -->
    <jar jarfile="${dist}/lib/MyProject-${DSTAMP}.jar" basedir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="clean"
        description="clean up" >
    <!-- Delete the ${build} and ${dist} directory trees -->
    <delete dir="${build}"/>
    <delete dir="${dist}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

You then save that in the root folder of your project as `build.xml`, open a console and change directory to that project, and run `ant`.

For more information, look here: http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I looked at the link, but it looks very different to what I am meant to be doing in my exercises. I just updated my post.

Comment: Hi Lucas, I have yet to try that at the moment. I will solve this problem tomorrow and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

You asked what a *properties file* looks like. It's pretty much a bunch of lines in the form of:

```
key = value
```

That's it. Here's an example:

```
ivy.cleancache = false
ivy.log = default
javac.lint = false
javac.deprecation = true
```

Comment lines start with a `#`.

Now, what you have...

The two lines you show look like part of an Ant file. By default, Ant files are called `build.xml` and must be contained in a `<project>` entity.

```
<project>
   <property name="build.debug"
        value="on"/>

   <javac srcdir="src" 
       debug="${build.debug}"/>
</property>
```

The `<property>` line sets a property called `build.debug` to `on`. The `<javac>` line runs the Java compiler on all `*.java` files under directory `src`. The `*.java` files are compiled *in place* since you didn't specify a destination directory. Thus, you will see a bunch of `*.class` files intermingled with your `*.java` files. The normal course of events is to create a place where your `*.class` files can live without interfering with your source files and are easy to clean up:

```
<project>
   <property name="build.debug"
        value="on"/>

   <mkdir dir="target/classes"/>

   <javac srcdir="src" 
       destdir="target/classes"/>
       debug="${build.debug}"/>
</property>
```

Now, when you run your script, it will place all of the `*.class` files under the `target/classes` directory.